react js filter() method and data
I have a state called allDatas in react js, where there are data such as photos and text in the form of objects, and I get the page ID from the params, and now, using the filter() method, I asked that the object whose ID matches the ID params is equal to get its data and save it in another state, but it does not give me the data and gives me an empty array, where is the problem? thank you
let params = useParams()

const [allDatas, setAllDatas] = useState(AllCoursesData)
const [buyData, setBuyData] = useState([])
  
useEffect(() => {
  const filterData = allDatas.filter(data => data.id === params)
  
  if (filterData.length > 0) {
    setBuyData(filterData)
  }
  console.log(filterData);  
}, [params])


Is params an id?

you probably need to extract param before compare   let { id } = useParams();

Brother, thank you for your answer, but it still gives me an empty array, if you can help me, you will be doing me a great favor.

params is an object, so you likely meant to destructure and compare the actual route path parameter, e.g. something like const { id } = useParams(); and data => data.id === id. Please [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] since it seems you have already tried the above and it's still not working as expected for some reason.

You're getting an empty array returned from the filter() method because you're matching data.id with params instead of params.id. The useParams() hook returns an object. You should refactor your code as follows:
let params = useParams()

const [allDatas, setAllDatas] = useState(AllCoursesData)

const [buyData, setBuyData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   const filterData = allDatas.filter(data => data.id === params.id) //This assumes your url params is named "id";

   if (filterData.length > 0) {
      setBuyData(filterData)
    }


}, [params.id, allDatas])

This should solve your issue.

Brother, thank you for your answer, but it still gives me an empty array, if you can help me, you will be doing me a great favor.

is your url params named "id"? and are there existing data in the AllCoursesData that is passed into the useState() hook?

When I write push() at the end, inside () vs code, it displays the data values, how to add them to the state?

yes , I checked them all

bro can u send me your instagram or telegram id to i send you picture of files and codes?

You can include a link to the github repo for the project so it can be properly looked at.

thanks a lot my brother link : https://github.com/arvinfaraji/react.git  The name of the file that contains these codes is BuyCoursePage and the name of the data file is AllCoursesdata. If you could help me, you would be doing me a huge favor because this is very important to me.
